# Jgit clone with git lfs enabled repository not working

Tags: java, git-clone, jgit, git-lfs

**Current setup**

I have a repository which is git lfs is enabled. There is another level of authentication present for accessing the drive where lfs content is stored. When I run the below code from command prompt it asks for the username and password for accessing the lfs content, as shown below.

[image: JGIT LFS issue]

If we use another repository where there is no authentication for the lfs content, then everything works fine.
Please let me know how could I suppress the authentication from JGIT or how can I skip the fetching of LFS content.
Please let me know if I am doing anything wrong.

Details:

1) Using following JGit version 4.9.0.201710071750-r

2) git lfs is installed

Code Snippet

```
public static void syncRepository(String uname, String pwd, String url, String destDir) throws Exception{
    String branch =  "refs/heads/master";
    System.out.println("Cloning from ["+url+"] branch ["+branch+"] to ["+destDir.toString()+"]");
    String workingDirPath = null;
    try {
        if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(destDir)) {
            workingDirPath = FilenameUtils.normalize(destDir);
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Working directory for code sync not found : " + destDir);
        }
        Path path = Paths.get(workingDirPath);
        System.out.println("Deleting '" +workingDirPath+ "' and re-creating empty destination dir" );
        recursivelyDelete(path.toFile());
        Files.createDirectories(Paths.get(workingDirPath));
        Path targetPath = path.resolve("");

        // clone repository
        Git git = cloneRepository(url, uname, pwd, branch, targetPath);
        System.out.println("Git revision # " + getLastHash(git));
        System.out.println("SYNC Repository completed");
    } catch (GitAPIException e) {
        // if the import fails then we should try to remove the created directory
        System.out.println("Failed to clone git repository."+ e);
        throw new Exception("Failed to clone git repository", e);
    }
}
private static Git cloneRepository(String url, String username, String password, String branch, Path targetPath)
        throws Exception {
    Git result;
    try {
        CloneCommand cloneCommand = Git.cloneRepository()
                .setProgressMonitor(new TextProgressMonitor(new PrintWriter(System.out)))
                .setURI(url).setBranch(branch)
                .setDirectory(targetPath.toFile())
                .setTimeout(300)
                .setTransportConfigCallback(new TransportConfigCallback() {
                    public void configure(Transport transport) {
                        transport.setTimeout(300);
                    }
                });
        setCredentials(cloneCommand, username, password);
        result = cloneCommand.call();
        return result;
    } catch (GitAPIException e) {
        // if the import fails then we should try to remove the created directory
        throw new Exception("Failed to clone git repository", e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be related to this bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=535814

Looking at the code, SmudgeFilter.downloadLfsResource() uses getLfsConnection(), which handles SSH authentication but not HTTP authentication.

At least in my testing the download fails with with a 401 exception (not authorized) rather than prompting for credentials.